# How to switch user if the Screen is Lock

Tags: rhel, users, desktop

Sometime when I have to do something on a server I find that the screen is locked and I don't know the password of that user to unlock it in order to switch the user.

So I need to know how to switch the user even if the screen is locked by a different user.

OS is RedHat 5.*

Comment: Depending on what is locking the screen, this may not be possible. What is locking the screen?

Comment: Well its a simple User lock like when u press CTRL+ALT+L it locks the screen and remains lock until user enters the password.

Comment: And what is the *process* being launched by that shortcut?

Comment: Most probably the question is: Are you running KDE, Gnome, or something else. Maybe it is just enough to switch to the console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and do whatever you want.

Comment: Redhat is using gnome. Yes I actually did ALT+CTRL+F1-7 but the thing is it enables only Text mode or Run Level 3. I cant use Run Level 5 or graphical view(GUI) . Simply put I dont know how to Enable GUI even If i switch using CTRL+ALT+f1

Comment: Doesn't the screen lock offer to change users?

Comment: Well No. In Redhat 5.X there is no such option. In redhat 6 I think there is option but not in rhel 5